# python how to get BytesIO allocated memory length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code i am using to test the memory allocation

```
import pycurl
import io


url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
buf = io.BytesIO()


print(len(buf.getvalue()))   #here i am getting 0 as length


c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10)
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 10)
c.setopt(c.ENCODING, 'gzip')
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
c.setopt(c.IPRESOLVE, c.IPRESOLVE_V4)
c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.perform()
c.close()

print(len(buf.getvalue()))    #here length of the dowloaded file


print(buf.getvalue())
buf.close()
```

How to get the allocated buffer/memory length by BytesIO ?
what am i doing wrong here ? python doesn't allocate fixed buffer length ?

Comment: show the stack trace.

Comment: Why not use a more decent client library such as [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/)?

Comment: @WeaselFox there is no errror i just want to know how to get the allocated memory length

Comment: You didn't write anything into the stream so its contents are empty. What's the issue? What memory allocation are you talking about?

Comment: @interjay python doesn't allocate fixed memory size for buffers ?

Comment: No, that couldn't work because it doesn't know what size is needed. It reallocates when needed.

Comment: @interjay how can i allocate a fixed amount of memory `e.g. 50 KB` ?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by allocated buffer/memory length, but if you want the length of the user data stored in the `BytesIO` object you can do

```
>>> bio = io.BytesIO()
>>> bio.getbuffer().nbytes
0
>>> bio.write(b'here is some data')
17
>>> bio.getbuffer().nbytes
17
```

But this seems equivalent to the `len(buf.getvalue())` that you are currently using.

The actual size of the BytesIO object can be found using [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

```
>>> bio = io.BytesIO()
>>> sys.getsizeof(bio)
104
```

Or you could be nasty and call `__sizeof__()` directly (which is like `sys.getsizeof()` but without garbage collector overhead applicable to the object):

```
>>> bio = io.BytesIO()
>>> bio.__sizeof__()
72
```

Memory for `BytesIO` is allocated as required, and some buffering does take place:

```
>>> bio = io.BytesIO()
>>> for i in range(20):
...     _=bio.write(b'a')
...     print(bio.getbuffer().nbytes, sys.getsizeof(bio), bio.__sizeof__())
...
1 106 74
2 106 74
3 108 76
4 108 76
5 110 78
6 110 78
7 112 80
8 112 80
9 120 88
10 120 88
11 120 88
12 120 88
13 120 88
14 120 88
15 120 88
16 120 88
17 129 97
18 129 97
19 129 97
20 129 97
```

Comment: So you are saying that memory is allocated dynamically as needed ?

Comment: @user4046642: Yes, that's what I was trying to show. If you want a fixed size buffer, there might be something in `numpy` that you can use, e.g. `numpy.empty(50, dtype=numpy.character)`

Comment: `len(bio.getbuffer())` also returns the same number

Answer (score 15):

`io.BytesIO()` returns a standard file object which has function `tell()`. It reports the current descriptor position and does not copy the whole buffer out to compute total size as `len(bio.getvalue())` of `bio.getbuffer().nbytes`. It is a very fast and simple method to get the exact size of used memory in the buffer object.

However, if you preset your buffer, `tell()` will point at the beginning of the buffer and return 0, but the buffer size is not zero. In this case, you can move the pointer to the end of the buffer `seek(0,2)`, which will report the total buffer size without copying the whole buffer into another chank of the memory.

I posted and recently updated an example code and a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030779/1887559)

Comment: **-1. That's WRONG. Do NOT hack with the `tell()` command.** (Docs: "`tell()` returns the current stream position as an opaque number. **The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage.")** You should **instead use** `foo.getbuffer().nbytes`, as [the docs explain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getbuffer): "Return a readable and writable view over the contents of the buffer **without copying them."** Checking size via that method creates a simple reference (pointer) to the internal buffer and then checks its size. It's very fast.

Comment: @MitchMcMabers - it isn't a right argument, I know, but I've been using this method since Python 2.4 or even earlier and never had any problems. I don't know when they introduced a view in `getbuffer`, but when I first time encountered this problem it actually did copy buffer into memory and crashed my app by the memory overflow. It may be "wrong" or less accurate right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tracemalloc` to get indirect information about the size of objects, by wrapping memory events in `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()`

Do note that active threads (if any) and side effects of your program will affect the output, but it may also be more representative of the real memory cost if many samples are taken, as shown below.

```py
>>> import tracemalloc
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> tracemalloc.start()
>>>
>>> memory_traces = []
>>>
>>> with BytesIO() as bytes_fh:
...     # returns (current memory usage, peak memory usage)
        # ..but only since calling .start()
...     memory_traces.append(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
...     bytes_fh.write(b'a' * (1024**2))  # create 1MB of 'a'
...     memory_traces.append(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
...
1048576
>>> print("used_memory = {}b".format(memory_traces[1][0] - memory_traces[0][0]))
used_memory = 1048870b
>>> 1048870 - 1024**2  # show small overhead
294
```