# Google drive python api: export never completes.

Tags: python, google-drive-api

### Summary:

I have an issue where sometimes a the google-drive-sdk for python does not detect the end of the document being exported. It seems to think that the google document is of infinite size.

### Background, source code and tutorials I followed:

I am working on my own python based google-drive backup script (one with a nice CLI interface for browsing around). [git link for source code](https://github.com/SpiRaiL/google_drive_cli)

Its still in the making and currently only finds new files and downloads them (with 'pull' command).

To do the most important google-drive commands, I followed the official google drive api tutorials for downloading media. [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

### What works:

When a document or file is a non-google-docs document, the file is downloaded properly. However, when I try to "export" a file. I see that I need to use a different mimeType. I have a dictionary for this.

For example: I map `application/vnd.google-apps.document` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` when exporting a document.

When **downloading google documents documents** from google drive, this seems to work fine. By this I mean: my while loop with the code `status, done = downloader.next_chunk()` will eventual set `done` to `true` and the download completes.

### What does not work:

However, on some files, the `done` flag never gets to `true` and script will download forever. This eventually amounts to several Gb. Perhaps I am looking for the wrong flag that says the file is complete when doing an export. I am surprised that google-drive never throws an error. Anybody know what could cause this?

### Current status

For now I have exporting of google documents disabled in my code.

When I use scripts like "[drive by rakyll](https://github.com/rakyll/drive)" (at least the version I have) just puts a link to the online copy. I would really like to do a proper export so that my offline system can maintain a complete backup of everything on drive.

P.s. It's fine to put "you should use this service instead of the api" for the sake of others finding this page. I know that there are other services out there for this, but I'm really looking to explore the drive-api functions for integration with my own other systems.

Comment: From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export), make sure that the requests are [authorized](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) by an authenticated user through the OAuth 2.0 protocol. In addition to other [scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes) an application might need (such as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`), all applications attempting to import or export Google Apps Script projects must request the special scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts`.

Comment: I have it set to full scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. Also, if the scope was wrong, I would not be seeing that it does in-fact work for some of the exports just fine. I think it has something to do with pulling multiple chunks.

Comment: Same here! Did you find the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I found the problem. I'm using the v3 API, copied the Python code from the Google's site. The API call never completes because (as it took me a while to discover), the HTTP call doesn't return the Content-Length. I couldn't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I found a pseudo solution here.

The problem is that the Google API never returns the Content-Length and the response is done in Chunks. However, either the chunk returned is wrong, or the Python API is not able to process it correctly.

What I did was, grab the code for the `MediaIoBaseDownload` [from here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py)

I left all the same, but changed this part:

```
if 'content-range' in resp:
    content_range = resp['content-range']
    length = content_range.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    self._total_size = int(length)
elif 'content-length' in resp:
    self._total_size = int(resp['content-length'])
else:
    # PSEUDO BUG FIX: No content-length, no chunk info, cut the response here.
    self._total_size = self._progress
```

The `else` at the end is what I've added. I've also changed the default chunk size by setting `DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 2*1024*1024`. Also you will have to copy a few imports from that file, including this one `from googleapiclient.http import _retry_request, _should_retry_response`

Of course this is not a solution, it just says "*if I don't understand the response, just stop it here*". This will probably make some exports not work, but at least it doesn't kill the server. This is only until we can find a good solution.

**UPDATE:**

Bug is already reported here: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/15

and as of January 2017, the only workaround is to not use `MediaIoBaseDownload` and do this instead (not suitable to large files):

```
req = service.files().export(fileId=file_id, mimeType=mimeType)
resp = req.execute(http=http)
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue with the empty `content-length` when trying to export a file for download.  I used `len()` around `stream.getvalue()` to get the file length and it works now.  Not sure about the performance, though.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827055/python-how-to-get-iobytes-allocated-memory-length

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this and it's works with the following library:

```
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-api-python-client
google-auth-httplib2
```

This is the snippet I'm using:

```
from apiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def download_google_document_from_drive(self, file_id):
    try:

        request = self.service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
        return fh
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error downloading file from Google Drive: %s' % e)
```

You can write the file stream to a file:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=fh.getvalue())
```